# Installing Boost 1.48.0 on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I'm trying to build and install Boost 1.48.0 on OS X.
I'd like boost to be installed /usr/local to allow my autotooled application to be build quickly.

I've run:

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=regex
$ ./b2
$ ./b2 install
```

At which point boost hangs at:

```
$ ./b2 install
Performing configuration checks

- has_icu builds           : no
```

And then nothing.

How do you install boost on OS X?

Also, I'd like to steer clear of MacPorts and fink if possible.

Thanks, Jonathan.

Comment: I tried doing it manually by coping the boost_regex.a file into /usr/local/lib/ and the boost regex.hpp files into /usr/local/include/boost but it complains about not being able to find other hpp files. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this was the correct way to do it.

All that is required is patience, compiling boost may be quick these days but installing it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Yeah, it took 40 minutes to build when I ran `brew install boost --c++11 --with-python`.